# single algorithm to work on both directed and undirected graph to detect cycles?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, recursion

I have been trying to implement an algorithm to detect cycles (probably how many of them) in a `directed and undirected graph`. That is the code should apply for both directed and undirected graphs.

Using `DFS or topological sort` is mostly recommended in various posts. But largely, everything is addressed for undirected graph.

[This link](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~vernon/cs367/notes/13.GRAPH.html) describes one approach for cycle detection. To my understanding this works for directed graphs.

[This link](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/CC.java.html) has the code for cycle detection in undirected graphs. but I fail to understand how it ignores the back edge. That is it must ignore any cycles with two nodes, say D to C and C to D.
which means it must remember it parent as the DFS recurses. But the code does not seem take care of that.

Any suggestions welcome..

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For a Directed Graph - we keep track of the recursion stack. For an edge (u,v), if we currently are processing u, and we see that v is in the recursion stack, then we have a Cycle.

For Undirected Graph - we look construct a parent array while we are traversing with DFS. Similar situation, for an edge (u,v) while processing u, if we see that v is Visited && not the parent of u, then we have a cycle.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the answers for [finding all cycles in graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/546655/finding-all-cycles-in-graph).

You can transform undirected graph into a directed graph quite easily: for every edge (u,v) in your original graph G, put two edges (u --> v) and (v --> u) into your new directed graph T. Apply any of the algorithms that find cycles in a directed graph on T. However, notice that any undirected edge transforms into a directed cycle (u - v - u), so if your original graph was initially undirected, you can ignore cycles of length 2 at the end.